# How to install an ipa file on iphone programmatically in xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have created an application in Xamarin.Forms which allows the user to install other applications on a button click.

The idea is when the user clicks on the button, the `ipa` file is downloaded and installed.

I have already managed to get the file downloaded in xamarin.ios but I'm unable to find some good resources on how to install the `ipa` file programmatically. I have already managed to get it working for `Android`. Note that I am using `Dependency Service` to achieve this functionality.

```
var webClient = new WebClient();

webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => {
    string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    string localFilename = "Messenger.ipa";
    string localPath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, localFilename);

};

var url = new Uri("http://192.168.102.3/ipa/Messenger.ipa"); 

webClient.DownloadFileAsync(url);
```

Could someone please help on how to launch the installation of the `ipa` file programatically once the download has completed in Xamarin.iOS ?

Thank you & Best Regards.

Comment: iOS does not allow apps to install other apps. Apps must be properly signed and come from a genuine source like the App Store or MDM solution.

Comment: Are you sure ? I just came across the following as an example : `UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl("itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://loqi.me/app/Geoloqi.plist");`

Also, I have to point out, that I am myself packaging the `ipa` file on Visual Studio. So, I have the bundle signing on my name.

Comment: That link comes from an article from 2011. From what I can tell, it uses Adhoc distribution which is a genuine source for an app during development and testing. https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev7ccaf4d3c

Comment: When I package an ipa file, I use the Adhoc distribution. Does this suffice ? 
Normally, I install the ipa file using Xcode. But what if I have to install the app on 100 devices ? I cannot perform the same process like installing using Xcode. I also cannot release the app to iTunes. 

Are there any other alternatives ?

Comment: If this is for testing, Adhoc will work. You will need to register all the devices. If this is for a company app, then use Enterprise distribution.

Comment: Is this correct ? : 

`UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl("itms-services://localPath);` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163145/discussion-between-ryantxr-and-expertgenie).

Comment: No, you can't do it in your own app. This url can only be used in Safari to install apps with enterprise certification or you have added your device in developer website with corresponding provisioning profile and signing.